# Inherit required fields from parent class @Schema annotation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, quarkus, microprofile

These are my classes for which I would like to generate openapi specification:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(requiredProperties = {"id"})
public class ArrangementDto {
  private String id;
}

public class CreditCardDto extends ArrangementDto {
  private String number;
}
```

This is how my generated specification looks like:

```
ArrangementDto:
      required:
      - id
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string

CreditCardDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        number:
          type: string
```

As you can see, the information that id is required on CreditCardDto is lost. How should we solve this issue? Is there a way to inherit the required property to child classes?

I am using Quarkus 3, which uses Smallrye OpenAPI extension compliant with the MicroProfile OpenAPI specification in order to generate API OpenAPI v3 specification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it, but I think that you need to use @Schema on the properties of the child class and indicate that it inherits the required property from the parent class!

Here is a sample that may help you:

```
@Schema(requiredProperties = {"id"})
public class ArrangementDto {

  private String id;
}

public class CreditCardDto extends ArrangementDto {

  @Schema(required = true)
  private String cardNmber;
}
```

This way you are confirming that the `cardNumber` property of the `CreditCardDto` is required, in addition to inheriting the `id` required field from the `ArrangementDto` class and your generated OpenAPI specification should have them now!

Comment: Your sample is same as mine (except you added additional required field - cardNmber). This doesn't work, id is not required on CreditCardDto in generated schema.

Answer (score 0):

In Quarkus you can choose the hybrid approach for generating your openapi specification.

Meaning: you can provide a static openapi yaml file and the dynamic part from your annotations will be added to it.

See this link:
https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#loading-openapi-schema-from-static-files

And also check the OpenApi spec for inheritance:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/